# Why does a Element Criteria Model Query with Strings on a custom element type not filtering?

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, elementtype

having issues doing the classic element type query, works fine with numerical criteria (id, price etc.) but fails on strings, (code, name etc.). It just returns all elements.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('GoWander_Trip');
$criteria->code = $code;
return $criteria->find();
```

Is there any step im missing in the setup of the element itself (code below)?

```
public function modifyElementsQuery(DbCommand $query, ElementCriteriaModel $criteria) {

    $query
        ->addSelect('
            trips.code, 
            trips.templateId, 
            trips.start, 
            trips.end, 
            trips.assetId, 
            trips.price, 
            trips.spots, 
            trips.spotsAvailable,
            trips.elements,
            trips.shortDescription
        ')
        ->join('gowander_trips trips', 'trips.id = elements.id');

    if ($criteria->templateId) {

        $query->andWhere(DbHelper::parseParam('trips.templateId', $criteria->templateId, $query->params));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer, simple mistake.

```
if ($criteria->code) {
   $query->andWhere(DbHelper::parseParam('trips.code', $criteria->code, $query->params));
}
```

was needed along with

```
public function defineCriteriaAttributes() {

    return array(
        'templateId'    => AttributeType::Mixed,
        'code'          => AttributeType::String,
    );
}
```

Hopes that helps anyone else who comes across something like this.